# What I have to do to use cout with opencv?

Tags: qt, opencv, cout

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 in QT Creator and I'm trying to print some output in the console but the console stays empty.

Here is a minimalistic code example:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
    cv::waitKey(5000);

    return 1;
}
```

When I leave out the line cv::waitKey(5000), everything works fine and the text is printed. What is wrong with this code?

EDIT: I changed the code to:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    cv::Mat image;
    std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

The console opens and displays something like "Press Return to close the console". When I delete the line cv::Mat image, everthing works fine. The console opens and displays "File not found" and in the next line "Press Return to close the console". When I use OpenCV code, cout doesn't work. Without OpenCV code everything is ok.

EDIT2: Now I inserted a std::cin.get(); after the std::cout line and everthing works. I don't know what is problem. But this is ok for me.

Comment: Did you try to press a keyboard button when your application runs?

Comment: When I press a keyboard button the console closes

Comment: This runs perfectly fine (without any delay, of course). Have you tried anything other than Qt? Is your output selected to `standard output`?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to `flush` the `cout`
for example

```
std::cout << "File not found" << std::endl;
std::cout << std::flush;
```

Comment: `std::endl` flushes the stream, no need to call `std::cout << std::flush`

Answer (score 0):

`cv::waitKey` waits 5 seconds (5000 ms) before returning, unless the user press a keyboard button, but this would not be catched since you have no window displayed. Have you tried waiting  seconds when you run your program?

Comment: Yes, i waited 5 secondes. Nothing happened

Comment: `waitKey()` works only when at least one highgui window is active.